# Unexpected token when @import -ing scss file into another scss file

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass

I have a main style.scss file which attempts to import other .scss files into itself.  when I compile the code using npm start, I get this error:

```
ERROR in ./style/style.scss
Module build failed: SyntaxError: C:/Users/XYZ/React/react-project/style/style.scss: 
Unexpected token, expected ( (1:8)

@import "_base";
        ^
```

I've tried putting it in brackets:

```
@import("_base");
```

and

```
@import("_base.scss");
```

and I get this error:

```
ERROR in ./style/style.scss Module build failed: 
SyntaxError: C:/Users/XYZ/React/react-project/style/style.scss: 
Leading decorators must be attached to a class declaration (1:21)

> 1 | @import("_base.scss");
                           ^
```

Here is my webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: [
        './src/index.js'
    ],
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel',
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1']
                }
            },
        ],
        rules: [{
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [
                "style-loader", // creates style nodes from JS strings
                "css-loader", // translates CSS into CommonJS
                "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS
            ]
        }]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.scss']
    },
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        contentBase: './',
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 8080
    }
};
```

I am new to scss and all of the tutorials I have found online tell me to import the files this way.  What could be wrong?

Comment: show your webpack config

Comment: That's a js error. You don't have a test for babel, it catches everything and tries to compile your scss as javascript. `test: /\.js$/`

Comment: Also loaders are webpack 1, rules is webpack 2+. Move to rules and remove loaders

Comment: Can you be more specific as what you mean by "move to rules and remove loaders?"

Comment: if you are using webpack 4 pls try to remove empty string from `extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.scss']` this will cause an error....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue - I migrated to Webpack 2 and changed my webpack.config.js to:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: [
        './src/index.js'
    ],
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', ["es2015", { "modules": false }], 'stage-1']
                }
            },
            {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [
                "style-loader", // creates style nodes from JS strings
                "css-loader", // translates CSS into CommonJS
                "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS
            ]
        }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.scss']
    },
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        contentBase: './',
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 8080
    }
};
```